# How would I have my table header stick to the top of the table, but still maintain the width of the tbody?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Take this table for example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwRbRy

I want to style my table so that it scrolls the `thead` stays at the top of the page, but it needs to keep aligned with the columns of the table, which the above doesn't.

How would I achieve this? I tried `position: fixed` but it doesn't keep it aligned. I also don't want to have to manually set widths on everything, as the content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Add to JS `$('table').floatThead();` This is jQuery Library and it does the work for you

Included script :
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/1.2.13/jquery.floatThead.min.js

Example in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvWRQb)

PS: I removed `position:fixed`.